# Change title in head on Archive page

Tags: custom-post-types, archives, title, custom-post-type-archives, wp-head

I'm having problems with figuring out how I can change the title on my archives pages. I now have a title like this:

```
<title>Jobs Archive - The Company</title>
```

But I would like to have a title like this: `<title>Jobs - The Company</title>`. Without the *Archive* . This for all my archives pages for all my custom post types.

Google didn't help me much, can you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change it via the category template (if you have multiple category templates you'll need to edit all of them; if you have archive.php, you need to edit it only there). Otherwise you can use the Yoast SEO plugin which have settings for naming the archives (actually I think that almost all SEO plugins have those settings).