# Issue with title for a page in wordpress for categories (Displaying CategoryName Archives)

Tags: categories, wp-title

The issue with a title for a page in WordPress for categories (Displaying CategoryName Archives).

If the category is Aptitude then page title shows Aptitude Archives.

How to remove Archives from the title.

[click here to understand the issue](https://competitiveexam.info/category/aptitude/)

[image: Issue with Page Title]

Comment: You can refer this related ticket: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/194780/change-title-in-head-on-archive-page

Comment: @JacobPeattie - this was helpful.